# how do I install praw

Tags: ubuntu, praw

I have been trying to install praw with *pip install praw* but keep getting this error message:

```
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 223, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 299, in run
    root=options.root_path,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 646, in install
    **kwargs
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 813, in install
    self.move_wheel_files(self.source_dir, root=root)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 1008, in move_wheel_files
    isolated=self.isolated,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/wheel.py", line 339, in move_wheel_files
    clobber(source, lib_dir, True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/wheel.py", line 317, in clobber
    shutil.copyfile(srcfile, destfile)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 83, in copyfile
    with open(dst, 'wb') as fdst:
IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/update_checker_test.pyc'
```

I have python 2 and 3. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try use sudo

```
sudo pip install praw
```